# Is it possible to add type when 'TypeNotFound' exception in SUDS raises?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds, onvif

When I try to load `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl` the exception `Type not found: '(IPAddressFilter, http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd, )'` raises. Is it possible to fix?

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('file:///home/web/www/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl')
```

P.S. WSDL file changed by me, just added direct link to the `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd` in the start of the file.

P.P.S

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 119, in __init__
    sd = ServiceDefinition(self.wsdl, s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.paramtypes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 137, in paramtypes
    item = (pd[1], pd[1].resolve())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 63, in resolve
    raise TypeNotFound(qref)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(IPAddressFilter, http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd, )'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding schema to import.

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import

imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')      # the schema to import.
imp.filter.add('http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema')   # the schema to import into.
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
s = Client("http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl", doctor = d)
```

Comment: may be you know how also i could add service tag on the fly?

Comment: @Kin not sure what you mean. where do you want to add tag?

Comment: When you try to run some service, for example `GetDeviceInformation` it raises the exception `Exception: No services defined`. Service tag looks like this `<wsdl:service name="DeviceServices"><wsdl:port binding="DeviceBinding" name="tds:DevicePort"><soap:address location=""/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service>` and show us target device where request should be send. Currently I adding it by hand

Comment: have you looked at Client.wsdl.add_children() method?

Comment: noupe, there is not so good description of suds... Could you give a link for description or examples?